# Google Street View coordinate data python

Tags: python, google-maps, google-street-view

I need to know which are the real coordinates for google street view for a GIVEN pair of coordinates using python.

In the google maps Python API there is not how to access to this information. (There is how to in the Javascript API)

I found a non-documented API that returns what I need, but since it seems to be illegal to use undocumented API's to get this information, is there another possibility without changing my programming language? Maybe connecting the Javascript with Python but I don't have idea how to make this.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe with https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python ?

Comment: This python API include: 

Directions,Distance Matrix,Elevation,Geocoding, Geolocation,Roads,Time Zone,Places. 

It doesn't include Google Street view service.

The nearest option would be using Geocoding but this is made in google maps, not in google street view level. So the real returned values are different.

Google street view service is in Javascript API

Comment: It looks like the whole google-street-view api is REST so you can access it by `requests`, the problem is what query should you use?

Comment: can you link the api that you found?

Comment: You are right.
Not only what query to use, the idea is a LEGAL one, without violating the term services of the google :)

Comment: Sure. This is an example:

http://maps.google.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=46.414382,10.013988

For the lat,lng=46.414382,10.013988

Comment: Looks valid and Google approved to me.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-image-apis/kdAxqMNwKhY it exist for more than 3 years now, but still no TOS...

Comment: For me it looks valid too, but in the google maps terms of services https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#9-license-requirements 10.1.a says explicit: " You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s). " :(

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the command below to get the closest road:

```
google.maps.StreetViewService().getPanoramaByLocation()
```

And then use it to retrieve the image. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that in Python...